# How to run full length cable housing to front mech on a frame without cable stops?

Tags: shifting, cable, cable-housing

I have an All-City Space Horse frame that has cable guides for full length housing where you use zip ties to secure the housing. But there are no traditional cable stops. The housing runs from the shifter all the way to the derailleur, uninterrupted. On the rear this is no problem since rear derailleurs have a cable stop built right into it. On the front derailleur (bottom pull) however I need to cut the housing somewhere in order to clamp the exposed cable to the derailleur.
What is the recommended method to install full length cable housing on such a frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the part you require is shown here:
https://www.ison-distribution.com/english/product.php?part=BBPSG7600

It is available from all Surly/All-City/Problem-Solvers dealers.

Single-sided, bottom bracket mounted cable guide, with integrated cable housing stop.

- Intended to fit 40mm diameter bottom bracket shells
- Includes M5 mounting bolt
- Direct replacement for:  All-City Cosmic Stallion, All-City Gorilla Monsoon, All-City Macho King, All-City Space Horse Disc

[image]

I used one of these to install a front derialleur on a Velo Orange Neutrino where it was also necessary to drill the bottom bracket shell and tap the threads. It's easy to do this but I think your bike will already be drilled.

You could also use a Shimano Side Swing front derailleur that takes its pull fron the front (which makes more sense than you'd think) as long as your chainrings are small enough.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this cable guide with integrated cable stop is exactly what I need. They really should've included this small part with the frameset

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised it wasn't included with a new frame.

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like you may be able to use a [clamp-on cable stop](https://www.sefiles.net/images/library/zoom/origin-8-clamp-on-cable-stop-226361-11.jpg). All you  need is a round steel-alloy frame tube that is strong enough to accept a clamp. If the clamp is located close to the point where the tube joins the bottom bracket, the frame tubing should be plenty thick enough. (I am not an engineer, and if you have doubts, especially where a frame warranty is involved, consult with a good bike mechanic.)

I looked up the Space Horse, and that looks like a sweet bike. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

That is surprising. I wondered for a moment if they only intend you to run it 1×, but I can see on the All-City website that they show it set up 2×.

My first thought was to get a clamp-on stop, as Ichabod suggests. However, there are some front mechs that have integrated cable stops, so see if one of those would work for you.

Comment: I think that's that reason the frame is like that. Many newer FDs have it built in.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite your situation, but I 3D printed some cable retainers with a curved back-side to match my tube profile, and epoxied these on.

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/56fo0JH2oJF-epoxy-on-zip-tie-mount-for-53mm-tube-holding-7mm-cable

[image]

This example would NOT work as an end stop, but it may be possible to make something that does that task.

---

Separately, there exist derailleurs that have a built-in cable stop, though those were mostly Bottom-Pull format like for a road bike whereas yours is likely top-pull, meaning the cable comes down from above.

[image] 
 From https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/914874-front-derailleur-built-cable-stop-how-upgrade.html